# How to get first value on condition in multidimensional array in javascript

Tags: javascript, multidimensional-array

```js
[['Mini MINI ELECTRIC LEVEL 2',31000,31000],['Peugeot 208 Allure Premium+ 1.2L PureTech 100 S&S',21590.00,21590.00],['Renault CLIO Evolution TCe 90',18795,18795],['Seat Ibiza SE 1.0 MPI 80PS',17755,17755],['Skoda FABIA ESTATE SE Petrol 1.0 TSI 95 PS DSG',19685,19685],['Toyota Yaris GR Sport Hybrid Petrol 1.5 VVT-i Auto',25340,25340],['Vauxhall Corsa Design 1.2 (75PS)',18040.00,18040.00],['Volkswagen Polo Life 1.0 95PS manual.',19795,19795]]
```

That's my array and I need to get name where condition match.

I have tried this but it says filter is not a function:

```
    for (i = 0; i < uniqueCarNames.length; i++) {

        const res = jsonCarsNewTable;
        console.log(res);

        for (j = 0; j < jsonCarsNewTable.length; j++) {
            console.log(jsonCarsNewTable[j]);
            console.log(jsonCarsNewTable[j][0]);



        }

        //var result =  jsonCarsNewTable.filter(function(name) {
        //    return name[0] == uniqueCarNames[i];
        //});

        console.log(uniqueCarNames);
    }
```

Comment: What did you try?? ProTip: [`filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

Comment: 2nd tip: Try using [find()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find)

Comment: where is `jsonCarsNewTable` defined in your code?

Comment: [['Mini MINI ELECTRIC LEVEL 2',31000,31000],['Peugeot 208 Allure Premium+ 1.2L PureTech 100 S&S',21590.00,21590.00],['Renault CLIO Evolution TCe 90',18795,18795],['Seat Ibiza SE 1.0 MPI 80PS',17755,17755],['Skoda FABIA ESTATE SE Petrol 1.0 TSI 95 PS DSG',19685,19685],['Toyota Yaris GR Sport Hybrid Petrol 1.5 VVT-i Auto',25340,25340],['Vauxhall Corsa Design 1.2 (75PS)',18040.00,18040.00],['Volkswagen Polo Life 1.0 95PS manual.',19795,19795]]